# Adding a delimiter in nutch crawled content

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I am trying to get specific information out of crawled content. As nutch dumps the whole text of the website all together, it's difficult for me to get a specific content. I want to add a delimiter to the crawled text content that I am indexing in elastic search.

For e.g. while crawling data from http://example.com/ the data that's gets indexed in elasticsearch is

```
Example Domain Example Domain This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission. More information...
```

I want it to be in the format

```
Example Domain | Example Domain | This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission. | More information...
```

Can we define this delimiter somewhere in nutch configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you want is to have separated fields to store different parts of the webpage, for instance in an ecomerce site you'll want for a product page to have the price, rating, description in different fields. In Nutch 1.x this is done by writing a custom plugin that do the parsing of the fetched content.

Your plugin will need to implenet the [HtmlParseFilter](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/java/org/apache/nutch/parse/HtmlParseFilter.java) interface and the [IndexingFilter](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/java/org/apache/nutch/indexer/IndexingFilter.java) and then in Solr/ES define the fields/mapping.

If you're going to write your custom plugin check the [headings](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/plugin/headings/src/java/org/apache/nutch/parse/headings/HeadingsParseFilter.java) plugin that allows you to extract the `hN` tags.

One other possibility is to take a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1870 that will let you specify which content you want to extract specifing xpath expressions.

Comment: Thanks.That was helpful

Comment: Glad it helped!